# Does the first book of the Dune series describe what members of the Spacer guild look like?

Tags: dune

I recently read the first Dune book, and I liked it.
I knew there was some movie version of it and looked around and found a 1984 movie, and other that I think is a series from the year 2000.

I haven't watched them yet, just a little from the beginning, and in both of them what I think is a member of the Spacing guild emerges from some kind of container. In the movie it talks with the emperor, tells him to kill Paul, and looks like a giant monster head. In the series it looks like a weird giant bat, and concentrates to make the space ship go into hyperspace.

My question is: Did the first book say how they looked like? All I remember is that is was a mystery.
Was there some hint that they looked like that and I missed it?
Is it made up? or are they using information from the other books?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Navigator is not fully revealed until Dune Messiah book 2. Until this in Dune one it's just vague speculation. I'm linking to Dune wiki as support but basic searching of book 1 on my part concurs with their findings.

> Leto's son Paul wonders if they are mutated to the point of no longer appearing human. A Navigator is fully revealed in the first chapter of Dune Messiah (1969).[dune wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Guild_Navigator)

Comment: I haven't read Dune for a few years, but aren't there supposedly two Guild Navigators present in the final climatic scene where Paul duels with Sting? They aren't described in detail but you get the impression they're human but one of them loses a contact lens to reveal blue eyes (like the Fremen) which is a result of Spice dependency.

Comment: @Darren you might be right, i believe that the full description of them looking unhuman is not until book 2. Ill double check the book, and update my answer

Comment: @Darren: There were two representatives from the Spacer Guild at the final scene, but they weren't Navigators.

Comment: @JoeL.: They were, though: The Guildsman seemed to stare into space for a moment, then: "Yes, you could do it, but you must not."  "Ah-h-h," Paul said and nodded to himself. "**Guild navigators**, both of you, eh?" "**Yes!**" (emphasis mine)